# Error when invoking Worklight HTTP Adapter

Tags: json, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing in Worklight 5.0.6.  I have created an HTTP adapter.  On my server side, I have a php script that accepts a parameter from the URL, performs a check on the data using php, and then returns a JSON Object back.
When I go to the actual page, It returns data like this:

```
[{"SUCCESS": "888888888"}]
```

Now, when I run my HTTP Adapter, I get these results:
errors: Class Cast: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable

I've tried to change the returned Content type to text, plain, JSON, json/application and none of those options work.  How do I need to return the data from the server so that the HTTP adapter can read it or what changes do I need to make to the HTTP Adapter?

```
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'plain',
        path : path,
        headers: 'accepts: */*',
        parameters : {
            'myparam' : param,
        }

    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your json array in an object. Worklight can't handle returning arrays :(